# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /key.p12: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm working on app in which I am using the `bigquery` in android app. I've created a project on API console.

I've put the p12 file in the assets folder of the application and have correct path in the code but I'm getting an error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /key.p12: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.

Pls help what changes I need to do to resolve it.

```
    try {
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
                .build();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Are you given write permission in manifest file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: It seems you just give the file with name, without root path. It might throws `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: How were you able to create a File object from your p.12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to read file from assets:

```
    try {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = am.open("key.p12");
        File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file )
                .build();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Create File from InputStream

```
private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

   try{
      File f = new File(my_file_name);
      OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
      byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
      int length = 0;

      while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
      }

      outputStream.close();
      inputStream.close();

      return f;
   }catch (IOException e) {
         //Logging exception
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: what is `createFileFromInputStream` ?

Comment: where it will create a file from input stream ?

Comment: could you please tell where it is creating file when I am writing this `File f = new File(key.p12.);` ?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-io-filenotfoundexception-how-to-solve-file-not-found-exception/ shows how to solve the "File Not Found" Exception by examples. Basically, when you experience the aforementioned error (No such file or directory); you will need to make sure that the specified "file: key.p12 in your case" is correct and refers to the file itself.
Can you try to specify the whole path to the key.p12 and see how it goes?
ex.: (new File("c:/key.p12");)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AssetManager and also you have another option to put the keyfile in the raw folder and get it from there.

since you are using android, I hope this answer will be helpful

[.\key.p12: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888783/key-p12-open-failed-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory/30975504#30975504)

have a good day.. :)