# .\key.p12: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-storage, assets, google-cloud-platform

In my android application  I'm accessing the Google cloud storage . I have generated the private key  **xxxxxxxkey.p12** .I have put my key file in assets folder . But while running the project it is not opening the key.p12 file . I have tried  putting it outside the assets folder , still no result.

```
     httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(); 
            AssetManager am = getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = am.open("xxxxxxxxxxKey.p12");
            File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);

       GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                            .setTransport(httpTransport)
                            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                            .setServiceAccountId(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(STORAGE_SCOPE))
                            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file).build();
```

**createFileFromInputStream()**

```
private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

        try {
            File f = new File("download/MyKey.p12");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            return f;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Logging exception
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I've done the same in java project.What makes the difference, is it because of android ? or the path to the file location is incorrect?

Comment: Have you tried to replace the Windows-Path Seperator `\ ` by an Unix-Path Seperator `/`?

Comment: u mean like ".//key.p12" ?

Comment: no, just as simple as `./key.p12`. The double-Backslash is only needed as this is the escape character in java, so you need to escape the escape character ;)

Comment: result is same , ENOENT exception.

Comment: Why not use AssetManager to read the file? Or put it in the raw folder, if you don't want to use AssetManager?

Comment: @Christine : Now I am getting file using assetmanager also as a raw resource , the problem is in the output file writing location .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggle I have got my answer, Thanks a lot for your support. Thumbs up!

File can be retrieved using using **AssetManager** and also we can get it as a **raw resource**

**Using AssetManager**

```
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = am.open("xxxxxxxxxxKey.p12");
        File file = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);
```

As a **raw resource** , put the file in raw folder inside res directory

```
        InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keyfile);
        File file = createFileFromInputStream(ins);
```

While writing the output file you have to specify where your keyfile actually belongs , in my case I'm using android, I'm creating the file inside the internal storage(emulator/device) inside folder **KeyHolder/KeyFile**

```
private File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {

        String path = "";

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "KeyHolder/KeyFile/");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdirs())
                Log.d("KeyHolder", "Folder not created");
            else
                Log.d("KeyHolder", "Folder created");
        } else
            Log.d("KeyHolder", "Folder present");

       path = file.getAbsolutePath();

        try {
            File f = new File(path+"/MyKey");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            return f;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Logging exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and that's it !